# Return the first of the month that is two full complete months back

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

(slight invitation to air opinion)

Is this the most efficient/accepted way of returning the first of the month that is two full months back:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE() - DAY(GETDATE())) + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is faster, but ...

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) -2, 0)
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8255/0)

Calculate the difference in month's from '1900-01-01':

```
DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())  -- 1356
```

Add the difference to '1900-01-01' minus two months

Answer (score 1):

Just two ops:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010301',GETDATE()),'20010101')
```

Which exploits the relationship between the two fixed dates to include the removal of two months whilst "normalizing" the date to remove day and time information.

---

Where this is nice is you can use it to achieve other tricks that are difficult to get correct without jumping through a lot more hoops. Such as the *last* day of the month two months ago:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010301',GETDATE()),'20010131')
```

which gets things right even if that month has fewer than 31 days